# Unicode translation (Java)

Tags: java, unicode

I'm currently reading the book "Beginning Android Games" and I have a problem understanding the following code:

```
int srcX = 0;
int srcWidth = 0;
if (ch == '.') {
  srcX = 200; //Jump to position 200 px in the bitmap
  srcWidth = 10; //A dot is only 10 px
} else {
  srcX = (ch - '0') * 20;
  srcWidth = 20;
}
```

I have a bitmap with numbers from 0 to 9 which is used to display high scores and the score while playing. The variable `srcX` is used to find the position (in pixels) in the bitmap for the corresponding number.

Ch is a character variable and is used to hold the current character in the string (which is either a number, a space or a dot).

My problem is that I don't understand why we have to use (ch - '0') in order to get the "real" number instead of the unicode number. For example, `if ch = "1", (ch - '0')` has the result of 1. If I don't use "- '0'" I get the unicode, which is 49.

Of course, there has to happen something, in order to have a transformation from the unicode to the "real number". But why results (ch - '0') in 1 and not 49.

I hope you guys understand my problem and can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If `ch` is `'1'`, its value is 49. The value of `'0'` is 48, so `ch - '0'` is 1.

Comment: You seem to already understand what's going on, so I am not sure what the question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character '0' has the unicode (same as ASCII for values 0..127) value `48`.
'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',  '9'
have the char values
48, 49, .., 57

If you want to translate one of this characters to a value ( '0' -> 0)
you can either do

```
c-48;
```

or

```
c-'0'
```

which does both the same.

Comment: Jesus Christ..of course. Even though it's so obvious and simple, I was too blind to see it. Thank you very much, guys!